# SQL Quoted String Not Properly Terminated Error - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite new to SQL and I don't understand why the following query throws an error in Oracle...

```
SELECT b.ATHLETEID, b.FNAME, b.SNAME, c.BDATE, c.CCODE, c.SPORTID
FROM “USER2_VF_S4530748”.“ATHLETE_V2” c,
     (SELECT ATHLETEID, FNAME, SNAME FROM “USER1_VF_S4530748”.“ATHLETE_V1”) b 
WHERE b.ATHLETEID = c.ATHLETEID AND c.CCODE = ‘AUS’;
```

I get the error ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: You apparently used a word processor, such as Microsoft Word, to prepare your code. Unfortunately, word processors often use alternate characters for both single quotes (see the characters around `AUS` in your code above) and double quotes (e.g. the characters around `ATHLETE_V1`). Oracle does not recognize these characters. I suggest you find and use a code editor - there are many of them - and use it instead of a word processor when writing programs.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing this as:

```
SELECT u1.ATHLETEID, u1.FNAME, u1.SNAME, u2.BDATE, u2.CCODE, u2.SPORTID
FROM USER2_VF_S4530748.ATHLETE_V2 u2 JOIN
     USER1_VF_S4530748.ATHLETE_V1 u1
     ON u2.ATHLETEID = u1.ATHLETEID AND u2.CCODE = 'AUS';
```

Not only does this use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  But it also fixes the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the issue of the `”`. Double quotes in SQL is represented by `"` (not `”` or `“`). The same is the case for single quotes. it must be represented by `'` (not `'` or `'`)

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT b.ATHLETEID, b.FNAME, b.SNAME, c.BDATE, c.CCODE, c.SPORTID
FROM "USER2_VF_S4530748"."ATHLETE_V2" c JOIN
     (SELECT ATHLETEID, FNAME, SNAME FROM "USER1_VF_S4530748"."ATHLETE_V1") b 
   ON b.ATHLETEID = c.ATHLETEID 
WHERE c.CCODE = 'AUS';
```

If you have all the names of the table and column in the uppercase then don't use double quotes at all, The oracle converts all the object names without double quotes into the upper case while executing the query.

```
SELECT b.ATHLETEID, b.FNAME, b.SNAME, c.BDATE, c.CCODE, c.SPORTID
FROM USER2_VF_S4530748.ATHLETE_V2 c JOIN
     USER1_VF_S4530748.ATHLETE_V1 b 
   ON b.ATHLETEID = c.ATHLETEID 
WHERE c.CCODE = 'AUS';
```

**Note**: I have also removed the inner view as it was not needed here.